# OmniSharp unit test not running

Tags: c#, unit-testing, omnisharp

Does anyone know why my unit test is not getting picked up? I am using OmniSharp on Visual Studio Code. When I try run the test it says 0 skipped, 0 failed and 0 passed.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
class Test {

    [SetUp]
    public void Init() {}

    [Test]
    public void calcualteBasket() {

        Package package = new Package(7, 7, 7);
        Package package2 = new Package(20, 20, 20);

        Basket basket = new Basket();
        basket.packages.Add(package);
        basket.packages.Add(package2);

        var finalPrice = package.Price + package2.Price;
        Assert.AreEqual(12, finalPrice);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about this, but you can try making your "Test" class public and then run your tests.